# What is an effective way to clean stainless steel appliances without commercial products?

Tags: cleaning, appliances, metals

Stainless steel appliances look nice and modern, but they are a pain to keep clean.  So far I've tried soap and water, diluted vinegar, and a damp cloth.  None of these really seem to leave it spotless.  What are some easy ways to remove fingerprints, water stains, and marks from stainless steel appliances?

Comment: They make a variety of cleaners specifically formulated for stainless steel. Please check your local home improvement or grocery store cleaning section for products. This is more of a conventional DIY/cleaning question and doesn't really need a solution [thinking outside the box](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/the-un-manifesto-commentary-about-the-lifehack-site-and-how-we-got-here)

Comment: There are commercial products for many, many things for which there are also Lifehacks.  In this case, the commercial products don't cut it, and I don't want to pay for them; this is an intractable problem, which requires thinking outside the box.  I would argue a good Lifehack could be the source of an invention (and eventual commercial product).  I'll post on the meta, but if the scope of the site is too narrow, you can't hope to attract much traffic.

Comment: Minnow, you can potentially *create* a lifehack about anything (e.g. "What is an interesting way to eat an apple?"), but we're not here to invent the most contrived way to do normal things, and there is nothing inherent in this question that would seem to need a "life hack." It's a simple DIY question. See [DIY vs. Thinking Outside the Box](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/the-un-manifesto-commentary-about-the-lifehack-site-and-how-we-got-here).

Comment: I agree 'interesting ways to eat an apple' is not a Lifehack.  Reading the most popular questions, many of the most popular questions don't really qualify for the scope of the manifesto.  "Killing a fly without a flyswatter" and "Not hitting your fingers with a hammer" don't seem profound or fundamentally different than this question.  I suppose the 4 other people who voted to close the question disagree.  I think that there is more activity on this site in the "DIY" category than the way you've defined a 'Lifehack', such that you many consider another site; I find them interesting and useful.

Comment: 'Best' way is objective.

Comment: As to whether this is a valid request for a lifehack or not I suppose the moderators will have to decide, but many of the products available to clean stainless steel just smear the junk all over the place. We are running a B&B with a semi-commercial kitchen, and have lots of stainless steel. We have tried several special products for stainless, soap, vinegar, etc. and are still in search of a good solution for the grease on the backsplash of our grill, which is how I came across this. If this absolutely must be closed, is there at least another SE site it can be migrated to?

Answer (score 5):

Oxalic acid, or cleaners with oxalic acid, such as *Barkeepers Friend*, are effective at removing stains from stainless steel. If the surface is *lacquered* brushed steel or brushed aluminum, though, they could damage the finish.

The cleaners themselves, though, may leave a bit of powdery abrasive residue that has to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

We find the white melamine sponges (sold as Magic Eraser, but there are generic types widely available) can work really well, **but** they warn against using it on the front of stainless-steel appliances without trying it in an inconspicuous area first.

Wipe in the direction of the brush finish, not in swirly motions.

Answer (score 4):

Try using **Coke**. I stopped drinking it after I saw what it did when I left a coin and a bullet casing in it.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr_yr0P6FgA)
[Article](http://housekeeping.about.com/od/savemoney/qt/cleanerssoftdrinks.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Isopropyl alcohol AKA isopropanol is very good at removing greasy marks from surfaces. Last time I bought it, I got it from a large pharmacists. Clean with soap and water first and when dry put a dab of neat isopropanol on a paper towel and rub the areas you want to get clean. Methylated spirits would work similarly but probably not quite as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has brought it up, you can rub a paste of baking soda on stainless steel appliances/pots/utensils. It removes stains and revives the shine.
Also rubbing banana peel helps the shine.

Answer (score 1):

I've used WD-40 to buff up my SS appliances.  not only does it clean things off well, but the appliance is resistant to fingerprints for a while, afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

When I sold my previous apartment I was told to use cooking oils to clean stainless steel surfaces, i.e. canola oil, olive oil, or similar.

To my surprise this turned out really nice, and the oil is usually easily accessible. Have used this trick ever since. Just add a few drops to a cloth and wipe it clean.